# 2D array with getElementsByTagName?

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to access table cells in javascript using the  getElementsByTagName method as shown below.  Ultimately I want to compare each cell in the array to another value, and be able to change the background color of that cell according to the comparison.

```
var cells = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
{
   cells[i] = cells[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
}
```

However, if I try to access cells[0][0], it returns undefined.  I feel like I don't fully understand getElementsByTagName is doing... is there any hope for this method?  Is there a more efficient one?

Comment: at no point in your code do you create a second dimension on the cell array

Comment: What does [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) return? "Array" is not the right answer.

Comment: You haven't created the second dimension. Also, it isn't returning an array. It returns an array-like object.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery it will be simple :

```
var contentArray = new Array();



$('tr').each(function(indexParent) {
  contentArray['row'+indexParent] = new Array();
    $(this).children().each(function(indexChild) {
      contentArray['row'+indexParent]['col'+indexChild] = $(this).html();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access any cell directly using the table element's [`.rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.rows) property, and the tr element's `.cells` property:

```
var myCell = myTable.rows[y].cells[x];
```

No need to build your own array.

So don't use `.getElementsByTagName()`, which returns a one-dimensional array. (Well, actually a NodeList, but you can use it like an array as long as you remember that it is *live*.)

If you did want to loop through all cells to compare them to some other value here's how, left to right, top to bottom using `.rows` and `.cells`:

```
var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").rows;
for (var y=0; y < rows.length; y++) {
   for (var x=0; x < rows[y].length; x++) {
      var cellAtXY = rows[y].cells[x];
      cellAtXY.someProperty = something; // your code here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this for each row.

```
var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tr')[rowIndex];
var cells = row.getElementsByTagName('td');
```

then build your array from the contents of these variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the table cells as 2D array

```
var tableRows = (document.getElementById("myTable")).getElementsByTagName("tr");

var cells = [];
for(var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    cells.push(tableRows[i].getElementsByTagName("td"));
}
```

And now you can get any cell on your table using

```
cells[0][0]
```